# Why doesnt my break work

Tags: java, loops

So I have a while loop with a if function in it. When the if function gets called I want to exit both the if and the while loop and continue down my code.. Yet break does not let me do this? What should I do.

As can see in my code i put break INNER; in the end of my if function and then INNER: outside the while loop, hoping it would jump here but i get a error even.

```
while(rob.getPixelColor(594,718).getBlue()!=34){
   System.out.println("3 start queue");
   rob.delay(500);
   if((rob.getPixelColor(754,428).getBlue()>40) && (rob.getPixelColor(754,428).getRed()<30)){ 
      System.out.println("4 start queue");

      rob.delay(500);
      System.out.println("scanning for popup");

      rob.mouseMove(750,408);
      rob.delay(400);
      rob.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
      rob.delay(400);
      rob.mouseRelease(KeyEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
      rob.delay(400);
      break INNER;
   }                                
} INNER:
```

Comment: Always specify what language you're using in the tags

Comment: java      AAAAAAAAAAA

Comment: Cool, I've only been using C+++++++++++++++++ in my entire life, need to try that ASAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP

Comment: You've got the label in the wrong place. Don't guess how to do something like this; read the documentation.

Comment: No see that does not work for me. It puts you back right over the While loop you broke but I will just enter it again. I NEED TO break it and continue down my code, not get put over that while function again.

Comment: What is the error????  (Never say "I get an error" without quoting the exact error.)

Comment: `break` with a label is *not* the same as a `goto` statement in other languages which is what it looks like you're trying to do...

Comment: @Have you tried putting the `INNER` label before the `while(rob.getPixelColor(594,718).getBlue()!=34)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use and boolean variable instead of a break Statement:

```
boolean exit = true;
while(rob.getPixelColor(594,718).getBlue()!=34 && exit){
   System.out.println("3 start queue");
   rob.delay(500);
   if((rob.getPixelColor(754,428).getBlue()>40) && (rob.getPixelColor(754,428).getRed()<30)){ 
      System.out.println("4 start queue");

      rob.delay(500);
      System.out.println("scanning for popup");

      rob.mouseMove(750,408);
      rob.delay(400);
      rob.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
      rob.delay(400);
      rob.mouseRelease(KeyEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
      rob.delay(400);
      exit = false;
   }                                
}
```

If you are in the `if` statement set the boolean variable to false and you leaf the while Loop because the condition is false.

Answer (score 2):

```
INNER: while (...) {
     break  INNER;
     ...
}
```

The label must label the looping statement.

Comment: It seems like when I get to the "INNER" part of the code I jump to "break INNER;" and not the other way around which was my intent. How do I do this? Changing position on the two does not work for whatever reason..

Comment: In this case a label was not even needed; a `break` would jump out of the first enclosing loop (while/for/do).